# How to put large data sets in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I've tried to put large datasets(about 200 folders) in HDFS.

But I got errors:

```
WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Slow waitForAckedSeqno took 72699ms; 

INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.111.3:50010; 

java.io.IOException: Got error, status message, ask with firstBadLink as 192.168.111.3:50010
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.DataTransferProtoUtil.checkBlockOpStatus(DataTransferProtoUtil.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:449)
```

I used this command for the number of folders, not at once: `hdfs dfs -put "eache folder" /hadoopPath`

Is there a solution to address these errors?

Comment: What exactly did you run?

Comment: I used this command: hdfs dfs -put folders /hadoopPath

Comment: Its possible if your namenode goes out of memory. Try to transfer fewer files.

Comment: Don't put them all at once. Also, size is more a factor than quantity. If you are putting a petabyte of data at one, it'll likely choke

Comment: I've been putting a gigabyte(about 130GB) of data.

Comment: And I didn't put all the files at once, I made a `.sh` file use the `-put `commands for each folder.

Comment: That sounds like a fine approach, I guess, but you may want to add a sleep command between puts while the previous files are replicated within the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.